# Size Classes Troubles

Tags: ios, xcode6

So I've been using size classes in Xcode 6 beta.  I started out by putting some buttons in the middle of the screen in the AnyxAny base class.  They showed up on the right side of the screen when I then ran the app in the iPhone simulator.  To fix this, I went into the compactxregular size class and dragged the buttons to the middle and spaced them out a little.  Then, when I ran it in the simulator, nothing had changed.  Why?  Is it just a glitch in the beta version or am I not doing something right?  It worked when I added a center x alignment constraint to the buttons but I still wanted to do some spacing. (and also, what's the point of the size classes if I could just do it using constraints?)

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yes I am @Fogmeister

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size classes are important so you can add individual constraints per size class (using the same storyboard). It has the flexibility to allow you to share certain constraints between all sizes devices and orientations, or just a single.

Click on each constraint you add and on the right menu, you can toggle which size class you'd like to add the constraint for. (It's the + button next to the installed check marks)

[image]

Comment: I completely get it now.  Thanks @tdevoy!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify different constraints for different size classes. Watch the WWDDC 2014 video [View Controller Advancements in iOS 8](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#214) to see how to do it in IB. If you can specify the layout you need without size classes, don’t bother; they’re just for overrides.